# Count square numbers in array using count function

Tags: c++, arrays

I need to count how many numbers are perfect squares in array of integer values, using a function from the *algorithm* library.

I have chosen the `std::count()` function to do that:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
bool is_square_number(int x) {
  if (x >= 0) {
    long long sr = sqrt(x);
    return (sr * sr == x);
  }
  return false;
}
int count_square_numbers(int *arr, int *arr2) {
  int number = 0;
  while (arr < arr2) {
    if (is_square_number(*arr))
      number++;
    arr++;
  }
  return number;
}
int main() {
  int n=9,arr[9]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
  std::cout << count_square_numbers(arr, arr + n);
  std::cout<<std::count(arr,arr+n,count_square_numbers);
  return 0;
}
```

When I use `std::cout << count_square_numbers(arr, arr + n)`, the program prints 3 as result (correctly); but, when I try to use it in the function, `std::count`, I cannot compile my code.

Could you explain what is the problem here and how could I use the `std::count` function for this?

Error I get:

> ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer [-fpermissive]

Comment: What line is producing that error?

Comment: screenshot: https://ibb.co/58BJcmF

Comment: Please don't post links.

Comment: I don't know which line is that, so I posted screenshot of compiler error, this error message is confusing for me

Comment: I believe the function signature of count_square_numbers is not correct to be used with std::count.  std::count does the iteration over a container, the function should just handle a single element.

Comment: @AnonMail `std::count` doesn't take a function as its third parameter (see below).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you are confusing the `std::count` function – which just counts how many values in the container/range are **equal to** the last parameter (which is a *value*, not a *function*)<sup>1</sup> – with the `std::count_if` function (which counts how many values satisfy the predicate, specified as the last parameter and should be a function or lambda taking an element from the range as an argument and returning a `bool` value).

Then, even when using `std::count_if`, you just pass it the actual test function (in your case, `is_square_number`, which fulfils the requirements for the unary predicate), rather than the full, loop-counter function:

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

bool is_square_number(int x)
{
    if (x >= 0) {
        long long sr = sqrt(x);
        return (sr * sr == x);
    }
    return false;
}

int count_square_numbers(int* arr, int* arr2)
{
    int number = 0;
    while (arr < arr2) {
        if (is_square_number(*arr))
            number++;
        arr++;
    }
    return number;
}

int main()
{
    int n = 9, arr[9] = { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 };
    std::cout << count_square_numbers(arr, arr + n) << "\n";
    std::cout << std::count_if(arr, arr + n, is_square_number) << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

See: [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count) for fuller details.

---

<sup>1</sup> When a *function* is passed as an argument to another function (as in your code), it is converted to a *pointer* to the function – hence the error message: The `std::count` function is attempting to compare values from the integer array with the function pointer.